# Export PDF from Illustrator or Indesign?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign

I am Export PDF from Indesign and save PDF from Illustrator, Dimension size are same in both software but PDF file size are very different.
Indesign PDF file size are very small comparison to Illustrator PDF size.

Can both programs create PDF files that are acceptable for printing?

Comment: Without knowing your export settings from each program, I don't really know what you want us to say.  You might have different compression/quality settings selected in each program.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, both InDesign and Illustrator can produce PDF files that are acceptable for printing. Your export settings will effect what happens when you export a file, and how large it is.

Comment: I  am exporting high quality print or press quality from both softwares but size in MB different

Comment: You probably want to try PDF/X-1a:2001 for exporting a PDF to print. Check with your printer.